# Vertically Centering Math and Text in Array?

Tags: arrays

One problem I've always had is trying to make text and/or math text vertically centered in either the `tabular` or `array` environments.

Take this for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\firstpartial}[1]{\dfrac{\partial}{\partial {#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{|l|l|}
\hline
\firstpartial{x}\left[f(x,y)\right] = 2xy & \text{Differentiate with respect to }x\text{, treating }y \text{ as a constant.}\\[4ex]
\hline 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to **vertically** center both the math and the text in both columns. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you have the `\\[4ex]`?

Comment: Not sure if that works with arrays or not, but without it, the length of the array was too small (it covers up some of the `\partial` symbol).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the `cellspace` package which states the following in the abstract:

[image]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\cellspacetoplimit5pt
\cellspacebottomlimit5pt
\newcommand{\firstpartial}[1]{\dfrac{\partial}{\partial {#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|Sl|l|} % Note the use of the prefix S to the column which needs be modified.
\hline
$\firstpartial{x}\left[f(x,y)\right] = 2xy$ & Differentiate with respect to $x$, treating $y$ as a constant.\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possible solution is to use a vertical rule as shown in the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\addmathvspace}{\vrule width 0pt height 4ex depth 2.5ex} % Adjust height and depth here.
\newcommand{\firstpartial}[1]{\dfrac{\partial}{\partial {#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\addmathvspace$\firstpartial{x}\left[f(x,y)\right] = 2xy$ & Differentiate with respect to $x$, treating $y$ as a constant.\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could define a "math strut" -- an invisible object with height and depth but no width (and thus invisible) -- and insert it where needed. I suggest using a "large integral with upper and lower limits" as the template for such a strut.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\firstpartial}[1]{\dfrac{\partial}{\partial {#1}}}
%% define a "big" strut using \vphantom:
\newcommand\bstrut{\vphantom{\displaystyle\int\limits_0^1}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{|l|l|}
\hline
\bstrut\firstpartial{x}\left[f(x,y)\right] = 2xy & 
   \text{Differentiate with respect to $x$, treating $y$ as a constant.}\\
\hline 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

At least in this case, `\addstackgap` from the `stackengine` package can add a symmetric gap above and below an object.  If the gap to be added is asymmetric (more above than below, for example), the `\addvbuffer` macro of the `verbatimbox` package allows for that.

Here is the `\addstackgap` fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand{\firstpartial}[1]{\dfrac{\partial}{\partial {#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{|l|l|}
\hline
\addstackgap[3pt]{\firstpartial{x}\left[f(x,y)\right] = 2xy} & \text{Differentiate with respect to }x\text{, treating }y \text{ as a constant.}\\
\hline 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]